# Can I reference other ids in the same collection in a MongoDB Schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of Users, each of which have a user.role which could be user, staff or admin.

This is a context where the staff need to be assigned to the users, and I'm wondering whether I could make a reference from one collection of the ObjectID of the same collection.

Could I therefore set up a schema do this?

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: 91823u918u24921123
    name: 'joe bloggs',
    role: 'user',
    'staff_allocated': [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

Here the staff_allocated will be another user, whose role is 'staff'?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly valid.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't really know the notion of hard references. In your model, Joe could even be assigned to himself (which you should check on your code). Behind the scenes, there is an additional query done to get the allocated staff members.